# Is this the correct usage of data cubes in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, olap, cube, oracle-data-integrator

Here's the situation:

I have a large table consisting of transactional data (credit card transaction records), and I am creating a dashboard application to visualize the data.

For example, I want to display the count of transactions for each customer, or the breakdown of transaction types for a customer, etc.

Obviously, I can't query the table on the fly because it takes too long, and also I don't want to create lots of different aggregated tables manually (like `customers_table`, `terminals_table`, etc.) because then I have to implement the update method too.

I did some research and I think what I need is a cube, which has all the necessary columns as its dimensions (like `customer_id`, `transaction_type`, `city`, `time`, etc.), with pre-computed aggregations, so then I can query the cube and get whatever aggregated data that I need instantly (**NOT ON THE FLY**).
So I have two questions:

- First of all, am I right about how cubes work, or did I misunderstand something?
- Secondly, can I create this cube directly using PL/SQL, or should I use ODI or other tools?

Comment: Do you use a plain database or some OLAP tool?

Comment: I use the Oracle database, but recently I've tested ODI tool.